# Bat file, auto log off my computer

Tags: batch-file

I wanna prank my office mates and I need some help.

I need an .bat script which will log off my computer after some one will press any buttons from my keyboard.

Can some one help me with this? :)

Answer (score 1):

With an [**AutoHotkey**](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script, you can remap the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> shortcut and create another one for Sleep (I chose <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, normally not used unless you use OneNote):

```
#l::         ; Win+L
Shutdown, 0  ; this is the code for Log Off
return

#s::         ; Win+S
DllCall("PowrProf\SetSuspendState", "int", 0, "int", 0, "int", 0) ; DLL call to sleep
return
```

There is more detail on the DLL call in AutoHotkey's help file:

```
; Call the Windows API function "SetSuspendState" to have the system suspend or hibernate.
; Windows 95/NT4: Since this function does not exist, the following call would have no effect.
; Parameter #1: Pass 1 instead of 0 to hibernate rather than suspend.
; Parameter #2: Pass 1 instead of 0 to suspend immediately rather than asking each application for permission.
; Parameter #3: Pass 1 instead of 0 to disable all wake events.
DllCall("PowrProf\SetSuspendState", "int", 0, "int", 0, "int", 0)
```

See https://superuser.com/questions/72789/are-there-windows-7-keyboard-shortcuts-for-log-off-and-standby